# Keep the same ID in Database synch

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net

I've created a web scheduler that allow my customers to take appointments with my company, all working well. Now I've another application in `vb.net` that doing the same with other functions for my providers, this application is used only by my providers, so in my own company and not to my customers. 
Sorry for the word around. Anyway, what I'm trying to do is create a class in `vb.net` that synchronize the client data to the web database. Both db are `MySql`, so I take an appointment in my client app and my code executed a query that add the same record to the online database.
 Here no problem, all working well, infact I've created two string connection one for client and another for the web.
Now, the big problem is that if I create eg. an appointment in my client app that have ID (auto_increment structure) `5`, the query that add this record also in the web database insert a different ID. This is a problem for me 'cause I can't recognize the specific record in the future. 

How I can solve this? Actually I use `MySqlCommand` for perform the operation.

If I missing some details I'll glad to provide, hope in a  help.

Comment: Why not us the same database for both applications?!

Comment: Simple, I need to working offline for my client app and have a db that must be even online for web app...

Comment: MySql allows inserting a specific value in an auto_increment field

Comment: @Steve could you show an example? I'm not an expert of MySql any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you have this code to insert data in a local database table, this table has a field called "nameID" and it is an autoincrement field

```
Dim nameID As Integer
Dim cmdText = "INSERT INTO myTableName (Name, Surname, City) VALUES (@name, @surname, @city)"
Using cnLocal = New MySqlConnection(...local_connection_string)
Using cmdLocal = New MySqlCommand(cmdText, cnLocal)
   cnLocal.Open
   ' Add the parameters values'
   cmdLocal.Paramenters.Add(......)
   cmdLocal.ExecuteNonQuery()

  ' At this point you could catch the last inserted id using the property  
  ' LastInsertedID from the same command that you have just executed

   nameID = cmdLocal.LastInsertedId
End Using
End Using
```

As you can see, this first query doesn't try to insert anything for the field "nameID" but get the value assigned to the field by the local database.

Now you execute a revised command against the remote database but you change the command text and the parameters collection to add the value for the nameID field in the remote database

```
 cmdText = "INSERT INTO myTableName (nameID, Name, Surname, City) VALUES (@id, @name, @surname, @city)"
 Using cnRemote = new MySqlConnection( ... connection string to the remote db..)
 Using cmdRemote = cmdLocal.Clone
    cnRemote.Open()
    cmdRemote.Connection = cnRemote
    cmdRemote.CommandText = cmdText
    cmdRemote.Parameters.Add("@id",MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = nameID
    cmdRemote.ExecuteNonQuery()
 End Using
```

The Clone command duplicates everything from the source (cmdLocal) creating a clone in cmdRemote, of course you need to change the connection and the commandtext to point to your remote db.

Comment: Seems a good solution, anyway, in the web db I've the auto_increment set also. You are sure that if I pass the ID from the client db all working well? Another question is this: I can create appointments in my web db, so what does happean if the record that I'm trying to pass from the client to the web have the same id of the db?

Comment: Of course no, the remote table is supposed to be a backup of the local one. If this is not the case then you need a two - way replication library that is able to keep your data in synch between the local and the remote otherwise the ids will be out of synch

Comment: Oh, so which library are available for my goal? I'm prefer a free library maybe also open source, but all solution are accepted. Could me suggest some of this?

Comment: Sorry, but MySql is not my primary database for work and I don't know anything to recommend here. You could start your search reading from here [MySql Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) and here [MySql Replication - FAQ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/faqs-replication.html) but this is a fair advanced topic

Comment: No problem Steve, but if you want realize a synchronization between two database, what do you do?